# need help finding and fixing "RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars"

Tags: python, scipy

[image: image of my code]

I'm getting the following warning:

```py
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

I've done some searching around but tbh I cant figure out exactly where or how I'm going wrong here, which obviously isn't helping me solve anything. Any help would be appreciated, thanks. It's my 1st post so sorry if it's not ideal formatting etc,.

code:

```
    def integral(integrand,a,b,arg):
    def real_func(x , arg):
        return np.real(integrand(x,arg));
    def imag_func(x,arg):
        return np.imag(integrand(x,arg));
    real_integral = integrate.quad(real_func , a , b , args=(arg))
    imag_integral = integrate.quad(imag_func , a , b , args=(arg))
    return real_integral[0] + 1j * imag_integral[0];

vintegral=np.vectorize(integral)

def f_integrand(s,omega):
    sigma = np.pi / (np.pi + 2)
    xs=np.exp(-np.pi*s/(2*sigma))
    x1=-2 * sigma / np.pi*(np.log(xs/(1+np.sqrt(1-xs**2)) + np.sqrt(1-xs**2)))
    x2 = 1-2*sigma/np.pi*(1-xs)

    zeta = x2 + x1 * 1j
    Vc = 1 / (2 * sigma)
    theta = -1 * np.arcsin(np.exp(-(np.pi) / (2.0 * sigma) * s))
    t1 = 1 / np.sqrt(1 + np.tan(theta) ** 2)
    t2 = -1 / np.sqrt(1 + 1 /np.tan(theta) ** 2)
    return np.real((t1 -1j * t2) / np.sqrt(zeta ** 2 - 1)) * np.exp(1j * omega * s / Vc);

t0 = time.time()
omega = 10
result = integral(f_integrand , 0 , np.inf , omega)
print (time.time())
print (result)
```

Comment: please share code instead of image.

Comment: It still runs even with the warning.  Errors give a traceback, warnings don't.  It is possible to change the warning settings so it raises an error instead.  But that may not be necessary, but I do see a number of divide operations.